# UIView subclass, released before to load it?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, release, layer

I'm trying to show a UIView subclass with:

```
-(void)pushChatNewMessage:(id)sender
{
    NSNotification *not = (NSNotification *)sender;
    NSNumber *num = (NSNumber *)not.object;


    OTChatMessageBox *chatMessageBox = [[OTChatMessageBox alloc] init];

    chatMessageBox.frame = CGRectMake(123, 60, 778, 208);

    chatMessageBox.toId = [num intValue];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationChatBox" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:chatMessageBox cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:chatMessageBox];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [chatMessageBox release];

}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
modifiying layer that is being finalized
```

I observed in debug that the dealloc method of the OTChatMessageBox object is called just ends this method.

If I remove the release of the object, all works fine...with a great leak...

I reviewed the init method of OTChatMessageBox and is absolutely simple, only a textView object and a button with a notification call.

What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance ;)

--EDIT--

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OTChatMessageBox" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        [txtMessage becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `init` method of `OTChatMessageBox`

Comment: Sure! :) But I think is correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadNibNamed:` returns an `autorelease`'d `NSArray` of objects. Therefore your `OTChatMessageBox` is `autorelease`'d when you get it from `alloc/init`. This means that your end `release` is causing an overrelease. The problem is that the `init` method should return an object which the caller is expected to take ownership over.

The `self = [super init];` is a memory leak as you never use the returned object and you don't release it, as you have `alloc`'d the object already you should at release it. In this case you would need something like

```
self = [super init];
[self release];

... grab stuff from nib
```

This is of course a needless `alloc/init` and you may wish to rethink how you are doing this